# Couldnt see Civicrm plugin when logged in as wordpress subscriber/editor and other roles

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home, settings, default-settings

I created different users for my wordpress page. When logged in as Administrator , I am able to access CiviCRM, but when logged in as subscriber or editor or other roles, I am not able to view civicrm link at all. where the settings should be changed?

Comment: look for ACL permission in civicrm - I guess that will help

Comment: Using CiviCRM 5.2.1 and WP QUESTION: I'm having same issue with WP Editor Role and I'm not seeing CiviCRM: access CiviCRM. I have CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ACL permissions for the specific roles in CiviCRM. Go to 'Administer>Users and Permissions>Permissions (access control)' then click on 'WordPress Access Control'. Here is where you can set specific permissions for user roles. The permission to provide access to CiviCRM in the back end is 'CiviCRM: access CiviCRM'. You will probably need to set many other permissions for these users depending on what you want them to have access to.

Comment: thanks. Didnt expect there will be a permission even to access CiviCRM. Great!! done

Answer (score 0):

In more recent releases of CiviCRM this core 'access CiviCRM' permission is now called, somewhat confusingly: "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API".